# converting text box value to an int

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the following error whenever I am assigning an integer value from  from Textbox to a variable.

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);           
int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text);            
ShoppingCart.Instance.SetItemQuantity(productId, quantity);
```

I am getting the error in second line of the below code :

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);           
int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text);            
ShoppingCart.Instance.SetItemQuantity(productId, quantity);
```

The Exception is

```
 System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: What `((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text` returns exactly? Can you please debug your code and tell us? What is your `CurrentCulture` also?

Comment: What was the text that you tried to parse?

Comment: What is the value of `txtQuantity.Text`? Where do you assign the value?

Comment: the quantity am getting is zero

Comment: @noushadmohammed Is it `"zero"` or `"0"`? Because `Convert.ToInt32("0")` doesn't throw any exception.

Answer (score 2):

The method `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception if the string argument is not a number.

For example, at the initialisation of your form, the value of the control is certainly string.empty, so the call will throw.

Try to test the value before converting it:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
int quantity;
string sQuantity = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text;
if(int.TryParse(sQuantity, out quantity))
{
    ShoppingCart.Instance.SetItemQuantity(productId, quantity);
}
else
{
    // do whatever you want if the textbox doesnt contains an int
    // for example:
    ShoppingCart.Instance.SetItemQuantity(productId, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly converting to a number using Convert.ToInt32(), use int.TryParse()`.

```
int result=0;

if(int.TryParse(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text,out result))
 {          
 ShoppingCart.Instance.SetItemQuantity(productId, quantity);

 }
```